# Integrating twitter but getting warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter-oauth

I am trying to integrate twitter to my application. i am following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlGI_vB0--o) as a guide.

I added libxml2.diylib (time - 06:50 in the video). I get 10 warnings, and i need to know how to solve these warnings ?

[image]

Comment: Adding the Twitter framework gives these Warnings without anycode